# Raspberry Pi simple LED and GPIO with Python not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, led, gpio

I just bought a Raspberry Pi and I was playing around with an LED, trying to learn Python. So my setup is as follows: my led is is connected to the 7th PIN of my GPIO and to ground. I made the following code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(7, True)
time.sleep(10)
GPIO.output(7, False)
time.sleep(5)
GPIO.output(7, True)
```

When I ran this code, the LED blinks once for 10 seconds, turns off and nevers turns back on. What can be wrong?

Comment: Do you want it to repeat? Put it into a loop.

Comment: You may wish to put a resistor in series with the diode to purveyors excessive current being drawn from the gpio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
while True:
    GPIO.output(7, True)
    time.sleep(10)
    GPIO.output(7, False)
    time.sleep(5)
```

It should loop the on/off sequence, causing the light to turn on for 10s, then turn off for 5s, and repeat.